# Выполнение функции при изменении размеров окна

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Есть скрипт, который делает размеры нескольких одинаковых блоков с разным количеством контента равными высоте максимальной из них.
Для определения таких колонок используется класс .equal-height

```
function setEqualHeight() {
    var column = $(".equal-height");
    var tallestcolumn = 0;
    // Ищем самую высокую колонку
    column.each(
        function() {
        currentHeight = $(this).height();
        if (currentHeight > tallestcolumn) {
            tallestcolumn = currentHeight;
        }
        }
    );
    column.height(tallestcolumn);
}
// Выполнение скрипта при загрузке страницы и при изменении ширины окна
$(window).load(setEqualHeight);
$(window).resize(setEqualHeight);
$(window).on('load resize', setEqualHeight);
```

При загрузке страницы скрипт выполняется, но при изменении окна - нет.
В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Для ответа на ваш вопрос еще нужен `html`. Скрипт на вид рабочий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется, у меня работает ваш код. Для наглядности добавил вывод в консоль, он срабатывает сразу при загрузке и далее каждый раз по событию *resize*.

**UPDATE**

Понял, в чём проблема. Высота колонок устанавливается один лишь раз и фиксируется, таким образом при ресайзе высота колонок больше не зависит от размеров окна. Нужно сбросить высоту элементов, чтобы они могли подстраиваться под размеры экрана, и когда событие *resize* кончится, обновить их размеры.

Поставил задержку в полсекунды, чтобы было наглядно как оно работает. Проверять на полном экране.

```js
function resetHeight() {
  var column = $(".equal-height");
  column.css("height", ""); 
}

function setEqualHeight() {
  var column = $(".equal-height");
  var tallestcolumn = 0;
  // Ищем самую высокую колонку
  column.each(
    function() {
      currentHeight = $(this).height();
      if (currentHeight > tallestcolumn) {
        tallestcolumn = currentHeight;
      }
    }
  );
  console.log('tallestcolumn', tallestcolumn);
  column.css("height", tallestcolumn); 
}

// Выполнение скрипта при загрузке страницы и при изменении ширины окна
$(window).on('load', setEqualHeight);
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    clearTimeout(window.resizedFinished);
    resetHeight();
    window.resizedFinished = setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Resized finished.');
      setEqualHeight();
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.equal-height {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.equal-height.two {
  /* height: 60px; */
}

.equal-height.three {
  /* height: 70%; */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="equal-height one">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </div>
  <div class="equal-height two">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div class="equal-height three">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: При изменении ширины окна высота блоков не меняется =(
Высота зависит от контента внутри блоков

Comment: Обновил ответ, проверьте.

Comment: Да, теперь все работает именно так, как нужно! Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Огромное пожалуйста!